# Python reading URLs from file until last line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have script which basically checks domain from the text file and finds its email. I want to add multiple domain names(line by line) then script should take each domain run the function and goes to second line after finishing. I tried to google for specific solution but not sure how do i find appropriate answer.

```
f = open("demo.txt", "r")
    url = f.readline()
     extractUrl(url)


       def extractUrl(url):
            try:
            print("Searching emails... please wait")
        count = 0
        listUrl = []

        req = urllib.request.Request(
            url,
            data=None,
            headers={
                'User-Agent': ua.random
            })
        try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=10)
        status = conn.getcode()
        contentType = conn.info().get_content_type()
        html = conn.read().decode('utf-8')
        emails = re.findall(
            r '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}', html)

        for email in emails:
            if (email not in listUrl):
                count += 1
        print(str(count) + " - " + email)
        listUrl.append(email)
        print(str(count) + " emails were found")
```

Comment: `readline()` reads only one line and you have to use it in `for`-loop. Or use common loop `for line in f:` without `readline()`. BTW: if you want to get list with all lines at once then you nead `readlines()` - with char `s` at the end of word `readlines`. BTW: and remeber to remove `\n` from line before you use it.

Comment: can you give proper example in the answer? I want to read second line only after function runs first line and complete then move to second line...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python files are iterable, so it's basically a simple as:

```
for line in f:
    extractUrl(line)
```

But you may want to do it right (ensure you close the file whatever happens, ignore possible empty lines etc):

```
# use `with open(...)` to ensure the file will be correctly closed
with open("demo.txt", "r") as f:

    # use `enumerate` to get line numbers too 
    #- we might need them for information  
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f, 1): 

        # make sure the line is clean (no leading / trailing whitespaces)
        # and not empty:
        line = line.strip()

        # skip empty lines
        if not line: 
            continue

         # ok, this one _should_ match - but something could go wrong
         try:
             extractUrl(line)
         except Exception as e:
             # mentioning the line number in error report might help debugging
             print("oops, failed to get urls for line {} ('{}') : {}".format(lineno, line, e))
```

Comment: but it still does not read the way i expect, it should read first URL, run the function extractUrl(url) finish that URL and after that goes to second URL.. All urls in in `\n`

Comment: Did you try this code ? If yes and it doesn't do "what you expect" then you'll have to more clearly explain what you expect and how this doesn't "do what you expect" - because it IS "reading first url, running extractUrl and after that goes to the second URL".  Note that if you don't actually understand what this code is doing, you may want to do the full official python tutorial before going further.